# how to pass strings from service to activity in android application

Tags: android, string, service

I am new in android application developement. I am creating simple application that contain service class and activity class. In service class i have called json array from php script and I want to pass that string from json array to activity class. so please help me to do this. I have searched a lot of this but i have not found the solution for this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Multiple ways, multiple solution

1. If after getting the string, you are starting activity from service then you can pass it via Bundle, putting it as extra  wrapping it under Intent, you can receive this intent on Activity simply by calling getIntent and looking for extra you supplied.
2. If Service is already running, then have listener mechanism implemented "Observer Pattern" 
   register this listener with running service, through which your service upon availability of data can notify back to client.
3. Send a broadcast putting your string as extra, and on activity has broadcast receiver looking for broadcast sent by your service.
4. Simplest of all, have a static method in activity, and call it through your service once data is avaibale.

Comment: Thanks Techfist for reply.

Comment: I have strated service from the activity and i have to get service string in that activity.

Comment: how you are starting service ? using bind command ?